# AngularJS services in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and looking for the equivalent of a service in AngularJS, specifically for storing data once and getting it throughout the app.

I'll be mainly storing the results of network requests and other promised data so I don't need to fetch again on very state.

I'm using Vue.JS 2.0 with Webpack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what u are seeking for is vuex, which can share data from each component.

Here is a basic demo which from my code.

store/lottery.module.js

```
import lotteryType from './lottery.type'


const lotteryModule = {

    state: {participantList: []},
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        [lotteryType.PARTICIPANT_CREATE] (state, payload) {
            state.participantList = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        [lotteryType.PARTICIPANT_CREATE] ({commit}, payload) {

            commit(lotteryType.PARTICIPANT_CREATE, payload);
        }
    }
};

export default lotteryModule;
```

store/lottery.type.js

```
const PARTICIPANT_CREATE = 'PARTICIPANT_CREATE';

export default {PARTICIPANT_CREATE};
```

store/index.js

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store();
store.registerModule('lottery', lotteryModule);

export default store;
```

component/lottery.vue

```
<template>

<div id="preparation-container">
    Total Participants: {{participantList.length}}
</div>

</template>


<script>

import router from '../router';
import lotteryType from '../store/lottery.type';


export default {
    data () {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
    }，
    computed: {
        participantList() {
            return this.$store.state.lottery.participantList;
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch(lotteryType.PARTICIPANT_CREATE, [{name:'Jack'}, {name:'Hugh'}]);
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    destroyed() {

    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Vue-specific services in Vue2 as it is based on a modern version of JavaScript that uses Modules instead. 
So if you want to reuse some services in different locations in your code, you could define and export it as follows:

```
export default {
    someFunction() {
        // ...
    },
    someOtherFunction() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

And then import from your Vue code:

```
import service from 'filenameofyourresources';

export default {
    name: 'something',
    component: [],
    data: () => ({}),
    created() {
        service.someFunction();
    },
};
```

Note that this is ES6 code that needs to be transpiled to ES5 before you can actually use it todays browsers.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export